# Exponential distribution constant?

Tags: probability

I don't really know how to start solving the problem below:

"Let a random variable X be uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 2] and a random variable Y be exponential distributed, i.e., $f_Y(y) = A\cdot\exp(−2y)$
, $y ≥ 0$.

Find the constant $A$."

By definition it is supposed to be $A=2$, right? Where's the catch?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I have $A=2$, too. Where´s the catch ? I don´t know. Maybe at the next part of the exercise.

Comment: You have conflated to problems. One for $X$ and one for $Y$. Each density function can have a different 'constant of integration' $A$.

Comment: The second parts wants me to calculate the distribution of x + y if they are independent. I don't know if that adds information to the overall problem.